# Cakephp Querybuilder : update rows with an identical field as selected one

Tags: mysql, cakephp, query-builder

My app's goal is to schedule posts through a franchise to its franchised.
The HQ schedules a post for a certain date and time, with text and potential image.
It creates the post with all necessary information in the database for each franchised(id, franchise_id, user_id, text, image, network, post_id)

post_id contains an id that is the same for each row that are completely identical besides the franchise_id.

When I add a post, it works well. But when editing, since it gets the ID of the post, it'll only edit the post that matches the id.
And that is fine when it is a franchised, it will then change the post_id to a custom value, and will be independent to the others.

But when it's the HQ(superadmin)logged in, I want him to edit all that matches the selected one by post_id.

Query builder is not something I'm used to and sometimes I thought about dropping it for standard SQL, but if it's there it's for a reason, so I would like your help in solving this with Cakephp's query builder.

```
public function edit($id = null){

    $event = $this->Events->get($id);

    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $event = $this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->data,['associated' => ['Networks'], ]);
        if($isuper == 'true'){//if logged in user is superadmin

        }else{
        $event->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        }


        if ($this->Events->save($event)) {



            $this->Flash->success(__('your post has been updated'));
            return $this->redirect(
                [
                    'action' => 'index',
                    date('Y', $event->date->getTimestamp()),
                    date('m', $event->date->getTimestamp()),
                    $event->company_id
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('unable to update your post'));
    }
    $this->set('event', $event);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making bulk updates using [updateAll](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates)

Something like:

```
$this->Events->updateAll(
    ['field' => true], // whatever fields you are updating
    ['post_id' => 'some_id'] // the selected post_id
);
```